# What does "::" in front of "::Rails::Engine" Mean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am looking at the [Rails Engine tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) and one of the code blocks looks like the following:

```
module Blorgh
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace Blorgh
  end
end
```

What does the `::Rails::Engine` mean? I know this is probably a trivial Ruby question, however, I don't seem to be able to find anything anywhere.

Thanks.

Comment: symbolhound.com is good for this sort of thing.

Comment: @muistooshort I fail to see how this question is a duplicate of what you marked as the existing article.

Comment: @ChrisPeters `::` at the beginning means the same thing as it does elsewhere, the answers even cover the leading `::` case. Disagree if you want or go searching for a better duplicate.

Comment: @muistooshort I think it is valid to re-open this question, because he is specifically asking what it means in front of a symbol

Comment: I also think it's valid to re-open the question. The linked answer 'sort of' answers the question, but not directly enough to guide the OP. `::` **in front of** a constant refers back to the host app. For instance, in an engine, `class FooController < ::ApplicationController` mean **inherit from the `ApplicationController` in the host app**. But, the referenced question doesn't make that super clear. A clearer answer would be valuable.

Comment: Yeah, alright, maybe I jumped the gun.

Comment: Looks like the correct duplicate was found. @muistooshort Thank you for everything you've done for the SO community though. We all jump the gun from time to time. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So, Ray has this exactly right. I would just like to add a further example.

Let's say we have an engine called Foo (original, right?) that is mounted in a host application called Bar with something like:

```
#bar/config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  ...
  mount Foo::Engine, at: '/'
  ...
end
```

Foo has an application_controller:

```
#foo/app/controllers/foo/application_controller.rb
module Foo
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    ...
    def foo_action
      ...
    end
    ...
  end
end
```

And Bar has an application_controller:

```
#bar/app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ...
  def bar_action
    ...
  end
  ...
end
```

Now, let's say we have two controllers within the Foo engine, like:

```
#foo/app/controllers/foo/baz_controller.rb
module Foo
  def BazController < ApplicationController
    ...
  end
end
```

and

```
#foo/app/controllers/foo/bif_controller.rb
module Foo
  def BifController < ::ApplicationController
    ...
  end
end
```

The `BazController` inherits from `ApplicationController` (no `::` in front). This means that it looks up `ApplicationController` in the current namespace (`Foo`). And so it will have the `foo_action` defined in `Foo::ApplicationController`.

The `BifController` inherits from `::ApplicationController` (`::` in front). This means that it looks up `ApplicationController` in the global namespace which, in this case, is the host application `Bar`. And so it will have the `bar_action` defined in Bar's `ApplicationController`.

Comment: awesome explanation thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Think of all the Modules and Classes hierarchically: it is looking for "Rails" at the top-level with "Engine" at the next level.

e.g.:

```
  module Rails
    class Engine
    end
  end

  module SomethingElse
    class Rails
    end
  end
```

`::Rails` selects the Module in the first code snippet, which is on the top-level.

`::Rails::Engine` selects the Class `Engine` which is in the top-level `Rails` Module.

Comment: I never knew this before! :O

Answer (score 5):

The `::` at the front of  `::Rails::Engine` means to lookup `Rails::Engine` at the top of the global namespace, not inside the `Blorgh` namespace.

Without contrast, without the `::` as in this code,

```
module Blorgh
  class Engine < Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace Blorgh
  end
end
```

the second line would be looking for `Blorgh::Rails` and you would get an error, `NameError: uninitialized constant Blorgh::Rails`.